# How to call Logstash periodically?

Tags: linux, bash, elasticsearch, logstash

We are using Logstash to read new data from database and send it to Elasticsearch. We would like that this happens periodically, for example every minute. How can we start Logstash periodically? What is the best practice for doing this on Linux?

Comment: You can use Crontab

Comment: You can use the `schedule` parameter of the `jdbc` input, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37613611/multiple-inputs-on-logstash-jdbc/37613839#37613839

Comment: @Val: If you post an answer I will accept it. Setting schedule => "*/1 * * * *" worked for me.

Comment: @jww: My question is about setting up Logstash and I can see many questions on that topic on StackOverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logstash). If you still think this is off-topic I will remove my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `schedule` parameter of the `jdbc` input. In your case since you want to run this every minute, you'd use the following pattern `*/1 * * * *`:

```
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/Users/logstash/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name"
    jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => "password"
    schedule => "*/1 * * * *"              <--- schedule for running every minute
    statement => "select * from table1"
    type => "table1"
  }
```