# Impact of integrating Elasticsearch with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch

I want to use Elastic search for full text searching in mu SQL server.
As i read I can index my SQL server by elastic search. 
My questions is about resource usage.
As I understood by indexing I must duplicate my entire SQL server database.
and I must take both elastic and SQL server sync.
Am I wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. I also maintain a sql server + elastic environment.

- You need a separate instance of elasticsearch running.
- You will have to index / insert all your existing data from sql server to elastic. There are libraries for almost any language to easily insert data.
- You will have to sync these two in order to keep the data up to date.
- In theory you only need 1 instance / node of elastic running, but it is recommended to have a full cluster, due to failover, etc.

Comment: And worth noting that the third point is probably the less trivial one.

Comment: Thanks. Can I use specific table of my SQL server instead of all of it for indexing?

Comment: Yes you decide yourself what to index.

Comment: And this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37613611/multiple-inputs-on-logstash-jdbc/37613839#37613839