# Transfer all tables from mysql db to Elastic Search at once

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash

I am able to transfer the data from one table to elastic Search at once.How we should do it for all tables present in my db at once?
This is the piece of code I am using...

```
    input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb"
        jdbc_user => "postgres"
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_driver_library => "/path/to/postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc41.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        statement => "SELECT * from contacts"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        protocol => http
        index => "contacts"
        document_type => "contact"
        document_id => "%{uid}"
        host => "ES_NODE_HOST"
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37613839/4604579

Comment: good but not great...btw Thanks