# How to insert multiple table values into each table?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elk

How to insert multiple table values into each table?

Using logstash, I want to put multiple tables as elasticsearch.

I used logstash several times using jdbc

**`but only one value is saved in one table.`**

I tried to answer the stackoverflow, but I couldn't solve it.

-> [multiple inputs on logstash jdbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37613611/multiple-inputs-on-logstash-jdbc)

This is my confile code.

This code is the code that I executed by myself.

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?useSSL=false&user=root&password=1234"
        jdbc_user => "root"
        jdbc_password => "1234"
        schedule => "* * * * *"
        statement => "select * from table_name1"
        tracking_column => "table_name1"
        use_column_value => true
        clean_run => true
        }
jdbc {
            jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar"
            jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?useSSL=false&user=root&password=1234"
            jdbc_user => "root"
            jdbc_password => "1234"
            schedule => "* * * * *"
            statement => "select * from table_name2"
            tracking_column => "table_name2"
            use_column_value => true
            clean_run => true
            }
jdbc {
            jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar"
            jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?useSSL=false&user=root&password=1234"
            jdbc_user => "root"
            jdbc_password => "1234"
            schedule => "* * * * *"
            statement => "select * from table_name3"
            tracking_column => "table_name3"
            use_column_value => true
            clean_run => true
            }
        }
    
    
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        index => "aws_05181830_2"
        document_type => "%{type}"
        document_id => "{%[@metadata][document_id]}"
    }
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

[image]

`problem`

**1. If you look at the picture, save only one value in one table**

**2. When a new table comes, the existing table value disappears.**

`My golas`

> **How to save properly without duplicate data in each table?**

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the document_id of the document in elasticsearch using

```
document_id => "{%[@metadata][document_id]}"
```

This is not a valid sprintf reference, so it uses the literal value `{%[@metadata][document_id]}`. As a result, every document you index overwrites the previous document. I suggest you remove this option.

Comment: `document_id => "{%[@metadata][document_id]}"`I'll delete the command and do it.

Comment: Resolution failed.